# More Variables for More Readable IF/Conditional?

Tags: c#, variables, if-statement, readability

**Question:** Is it better to have more variables to allow a conditional to be "more readable" or is it cleaner to have less variables but a harder to read conditional?

I read this which says less variables. I think their solutions look LESS readable ( https://techbeacon.com/why-unnecessary-variables-are-bad-your-code )
This SO sounds slightly different though: [Introducing variables only for readability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091766/introducing-variables-only-for-readability)

**Example:**

I have the following statement:

```
if ((memberIDandLNIsValid) || (memberIDandDOBIsValid && memberDOBFormatIsValid))
```

To get memberIDandLNIsValid I have:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Search_MemberID) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Search_MemberLastName))
```

Notice that Search_MemberID and Search_MemberLastName are two separate variables. I thought it was easier to read to have a combined variable.
But I have been told there are too many variables in my code.

I'm guessing the solution is to just leave it as :

```
if( (Search_MemberID && Search_MemberLastName) || ((Search_MemberID && Search_DOB) && memberDOBFormatIsValid) )
```

To me, this conditional is MUCH less readable now.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm sure its all personal preference, but when getting into a complex mess of both multiple truth and multiple logical NOTs, I would be totally fine to prequalify some into a simplified variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fine as is, but one technique you can use is to refactor your booleans to methods with more readable names.

```
(Search_MemberID && Search_MemberLastName)|| ((Search_MemberID && Search_DOB)
```

becomes:

```
SearchMemberHasIdAndLastName() || SearchMemberHasIdAndDOB()
```

You don't need to do that here, but it is a technique to keep in the back of your mind.